# gcc -g0 and without the -g option

Tags: c, linux, gcc

What is the difference between compiling without the `-g` option and compiling with the `-g0` option in gcc? Is there any specific reason behind giving the `-g0` option in gcc?
I tried compiling and found the "**no debugging symbols**" message with both cases in GDB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to the GCC [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options), you will find that it says:

> `-g`*`level`* …
>
> Request debugging information and also use level to specify how much information. The default level is 2.
>
> Level 0 produces no debug information at all. Thus, `-g0` negates `-g`.

So, don't use `-g0` if you want debug information.  If you do want debug information, remember to use the `-g` option both when creating the object files (`-c`) and when linking the program.

And compiling without `-g` at all and compiling with `-g0` are equivalent and there is no debugging information in the resulting binaries — as you found by experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options):

> #### `-glevel`
>
> #### `-ggdblevel`
>
> #### `-gstabslevel`
>
> #### `-gcofflevel`
>
> #### `-gxcofflevel`
>
> #### `-gvmslevel`
>
> Request debugging information and also use level to specify how
>   much information.  The default level is 2.
>
> Level 0 produces no debug information at all.  Thus, `-g0` negates `-g`.
>
> Level 1 produces minimal information, enough for making backtraces
>   in parts of the program that you don't plan to debug.  This
>   includes descriptions of functions and external variables, but no
>   information about local variables and no line numbers.
>
> Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro
>   definitions present in the program.  Some debuggers support macro
>   expansion when you use `-g3`.
>
> `-gdwarf-2` does not accept a concatenated debug level, because GCC
>   used to support an option `-gdwarf` that meant to generate debug
>   information in version 1 of the DWARF format (which is very
>   different from version 2), and it would have been too confusing.
>   That debug format is long obsolete, but the option cannot be
>   changed now.  Instead use an additional `-glevel` option to change
>    the debug level for DWARF.

And for completeness, about the default level `-g`/`-g2`

> #### `-g`
>
> Produce debugging information in the operating system's native
>   format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF 2).  GDB can work with this
>   debugging information.
>
> On most systems that use stabs format, `-g` enables use of extra
>   debugging information that only GDB can use; this extra information
>   makes debugging work better in GDB but probably makes other
>   debuggers crash or refuse to read the program.  If you want to
>   control for certain whether to generate the extra information, use
>   `-gstabs+`, `-gstabs`, `-gxcoff+`, `-gxcoff`, or `-gvms` (see below).
>
> GCC allows you to use `-g` with `-O`.  The shortcuts taken by optimized
>   code may occasionally produce surprising results: some variables
>   you declared may not exist at all; flow of control may briefly move
>   where you did not expect it; some statements may not be executed
>   because they compute constant results or their values are already
>   at hand; some statements may execute in different places because
>   they have been moved out of loops.
>
> Nevertheless it proves possible to debug optimized output.  This
>   makes it reasonable to use the optimizer for programs that might
>   have bugs.